# Read Google sheets with JSon (JavaScript), problem with save data [Object Promese] {}

Tags: javascript, json, function, promise, codepen

by hobbie I have created a pokedex where I want to register the shiny pokemons that I have captured, I have them saved in google spreadsheets, and I want to capture the data with JSon

I based myself on a youtube video (link below), and I modified some things, adding google spreadsheets to read the captured ones

This link have the project if you wanna see all:
https://codepen.io/willy587/pen/pojNLGg

Ok the problem is when a want to read my spreadsheets i have this:

```
async function getPokemonStatus(id){
    const response = await 
fetch(`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1x5Nhf8T4kBGxyLxCskHUNlF0_PScXrrl3Wrc5C7PDhc/od6/public/values?alt=json`);
    const data = await response.json();
    const pkstatus = data.feed.entry[id].gsx$estado.$t;
    console.log(pkstatus);//<--- show the status and is fine, works in that point 
    return pkstatus;//<------Here I try return the status because I want save in a variable/const 
} 

if (pokemon.id) {
   pokemonEl.innerHTML = pokeInnerHTML2; //Here is the sprite of the pokemon
   const status = getPokemonStatus(pokemon.id);// <---- When I do this save [Object Promise] {}
   console.log(status);
} else {
   pokemonEl.innerHTML = pokeInnerHTML; //Here is the missigno sprite, if I don't have the pokemon
}
```

**I try use .then** method, but it doesn't work either
I look for others examples in the web but nothing
I'm not a pro in javascript is my first code so if you can help me, I'll be grateful

you can see **All the code** in the codepen link, if you wanna work you there, Thanks

base code video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XL68br6JyYs

google spread:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x5Nhf8T4kBGxyLxCskHUNlF0_PScXrrl3Wrc5C7PDhc/edit#gid=0

this google spread is a example, the true google spread is another with the 800+ pokemon

Comment: async functions return promises, you would need use `async/await` or `then` on the `getPokemonStatus()`. such as `getPokemonStatus(pokemon.id).then((status) => { console.log(status); });`

Comment: I tried that and doesn´t work, because I want compare status value

`if (status == "Libre")`

Comment: You can't simply return static, resolved values from async functions or similar functions that return promises. Either execute the code that consumes this in an async function and await the resolved value or do it all in `then()`.

Comment: it's better if you add your `.then` implementation, so that we can be certain, whether you are using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks well I do this, put all the code into a then. like Alexander Staroselky said

```
 async function getPokemonStatus(id){
    const response = await fetch(`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1x5Nhf8T4kBGxyLxCskHUNlF0_PScXrrl3Wrc5C7PDhc/od6/public/values?alt=json`);
    const data = await response.json();
    const pkstatus = data.feed.entry[id].gsx$estado.$t;
  return pkstatus;
} 

if (pokemon.id) {
   getPokemonStatus(pokemon.id-1).then((status) => { 

 if (status == "Capturado")
{
  pokemonEl.innerHTML = pokeInnerHTML2;
  //console.log(getPokemonStatus(pokemon.id));
} 
  else
{
   pokemonEl.innerHTML = pokeInnerHTML;
}

   });
```